# What is the best hash function to store large random numbers in?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I want to store large numbers in a data structure, to do so, I want to use hash function, so that insertion, deletion or searching could be fast. But I am unable to decide which hash function should i use ?

And in general, I want to know how to decide a hash function is good for any particular problem ?

**EDIT :** I think a made people confused with using term "random". Here with random, what I mean is, I dont have any particular range of numbers from where I have to choose[any 32 bit integer], but I have the total no which will be given to store in the data structure like  some 5000 numbers. So suggest me best hash function for this scenario and why you conclude it to be best ?

Comment: [This](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html) should be able to help you... Or you can try combinations of these depending on your requirements...

Comment: Before you decide on the hash function, have you decided which *data structure* you're going to use?

Comment: If your large numbers are really uniformly distributed, *any* hash function, even the most trivial will do.

Comment: But why do you want to use a hash function at all? Why not simply store them in an array?

Answer (score 4):

If the numbers are uniformly random, just use a hash function which selects the low bits.

```
unsigned hash_number(long long x)
{
    return (unsigned) x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if your input numbers are completely random, using h(x) = x might still pose performance problems. Image that your numbers are randomly chosen from 0, 2, 4, ..., 2k, though random, none of them will be mapped to the first bucket of a hash table (bucket 0), assuming power of two bucket sizes. Thus what really matters is the information entropy of the input numbers.

An excellent choice in your case is the Thomas Wang's integer hash function, which is invertible and maintains a good avalanche effect(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect). There is an article that describes the Thomas Wang's hash function and its inverse: http://naml.us/blog/2012/03.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense to me. Using a hashing algorithm to store some random numbers is overkill. If there is something more to the problem, the choice of data structure will depend on what this something more is (which you don't say).

If these numbers really are random or pseudorandom then all you need is a stack or circular buffer - the capability to add (push) a new random number into the data structure and the capability to remove (pop) an existing random number from the structure. If you want to retrieve them in order, use a circular buffer. A hashing function is worse in every respect than a simple stack (or circular buffer) for holding a list of random numbers - it is more complex, runs slower, and uses more memory.

Most languages/environments provide hash functions which can be used (or are provided as) "dictionary" classes, and these come with guidance as to efficiency. Generally, you can make dictionary classes faster by allocating more memory - they slow down when hash keys collide. So the "density" of actual numbers amongst all possible numbers matters.

So if you had to hold 100 such numbers, you could use a hash function which looked only at the last 12 bits. This gives 2^12 = 4096 possible hashes, so collisions will only occur 100/2048 of the time, less than 5%. On the other hand, you are using over 20 times as much memory as you should. (This function is the same as taking the modulus of the number to base 2^12, and is similar to what Epp suggested.)

Writing a storage class based on a hash function which properly handles hash collisions (as it must), gracefully handles duplicated data, won't freak if you chuck it bad data (like every number the same), and is efficient, is not a trivial task.

On the other hand, implementing a stack or circular buffer is extremely simple, very efficient, and has entirely predictable behaviour.

Are you sure you aren't making this more complicated than it needs to be?